# Recording individual average and cummulative average and highest average score

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that calculates the average scores for bowlers, the team average score, and the highest average score on the team.

Problems:

1. I am unable to figure out how to display all the individual player averages at the end without displaying everytime the loop iterates.
2. how do I set up the code so that I can calculate the cummulative average and highest average score?

Below is the code I wrote so far

```
import java.util.*;

public class bowlerama2 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        int players;// for number of players on the team
        int games=0;// for number of games played
        int totalGames=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of players on the bowling team.");
        System.out.println("You must enter a number greater than or equal to three");
        players=keyboard.nextInt();

        //input validation
        while (players<3)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. You must enter a number greater than or equal to three for the number of players on the team.");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of players on the bowling team:");
            players=keyboard.nextInt();
        }


        for(int number=1;number<=players;number++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the number of games bowled by player " + number + ":");
            System.out.println("You must enter a number greater than or equal to two.");
            games=keyboard.nextInt();
            while (games<2)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry.You must enter a number greater than or equal to two for the number of games played");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of games bowled by player " +number+ ":");
                games=keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            totalGames+=games;

            receive (number, games, totalGames);

        }

    }
    public static void receive (int number, int games, int totalGames)
    {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        int total=0;//accumulator for individual scores
        int score=0;
        int average=0;


        for (int amount=1;amount<=games;amount++)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter the score for player " +number+ " in game " + amount + ":");
            score=keyboard.nextInt();

            //input validation
            while(score<0 || score>300)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. Score must be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to three hundred");
                System.out.println("Enter the score for player " + number+ " in game " +amount+ ":");
                score=keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            total+=score;
            average=total/amount;

            System.out.println("The average score for player " +number+ " is:" + average);
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: unrelated: formatting broken.

Answer (score 0):

1) Store the average values for each player in an arraylist.  So that when you calculate the average you just throw it in the list and have it already.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add(new Integer(average));
```

then access the list in your main method for the player's score you want

2) For cumulative average just iterate over the arrayList adding the scores together and then divide by the arrayList length.  For highest score make an if statement to check if the average score for each player is higher then your previous players highest average score, if it is set that equal to the new highest average score.

Comment: in order to access the list in the main method in which method should the array list be declared in

Comment: Your going to want to either declare the list in your main and then pass it into receive, or make it a class var.  I recommend passing it just because its better practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some kind of Temporary data storage. Something such as an Array or an ArrayList (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List al = new ArrayList<Type>();
```

For your case Type would be Integer. Once you have everything stored in an ArrayList then you can just loop through the ArrayList to add up all the values. Also to find the "max" you will need to initially set an integer variable as -999. Then run through all of your values and if the value is > max then set that variable as max.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess from the code so far that you haven't covered ArrayList yet, and that if you submit a solution that does use it, your teacher might be a little suspicious :-)  It looks like perhaps a couple of simple arrays would help.  You will need to obtain the number of players first so that you can create arrays of the proper size.  Use one array for storing cumulative scores for each player and one for storing number of scores for each player.  Populate the array values as you gather the input.  The stored values should then allow you to calculate average score for each player, team average, and highest player average.

The key is that there's the input phase where you're populating the arrays, and then a calculation phase (where you iterate through the arrays and perform your caculations), and then a display phase.

Comment: there is no maximum number of players only a minimum of 3

Answer (score 0):

1. avarage scores for each player. you can do it via string concatenation. first make empty static string. after each receive append new data to string. println result string after players loop.
2. for team avarage and highest avarage.

   team_av=sum(player_av)/players

in main method:

```
   double sum_player_avarage=0
   double highest_avarage=0
```

in your receive method return double value of player avarage.

```
double player_av= receive (number, games, totalGames);
if (highest_avarage<player_av) highest_avarage=player_av;
sum_player_avarage+=player_av;
```

after all:

```
team_avarage=sum_player_avarage/players;

println(team_avarage);
println(highest_avarage)
println(StringWithPlayersAvarage)
```

Comment: "avarage scores for each player. you can do it via string concatenation. first build empty string. after each receive append new data to string. println result string after players loop." - This is a terrible solution.  You are taking dynamic data and making it static.

Comment: but for homework this straight no OOP and no collection version may be more suitable. nobody expects student makes overcomplicated solution. may be he can use buffered writer output to flush data after all calculations